# Detecting touch on UIImageView from within custom Cell

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom cell layout with some `UILabel`s and `UIImageView`s within the `UITableViewCell`.

I have already setup the cells in Storyboard and linked up the relevant outlets. I have also already handled the cell being selected with `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

What I am trying to do now is link a specific image view from within the cell to load a different View Controller. I have the segue already setup in the storyboard.

How do I setup a gesture recogniser just from this UIImageView to the segue?

So I am looking for the following: 
If you tap the cell the didSelectRowAtIndex* is run as expected.
But if you tap the UIImageView from within the cell then the didSelectRow* is not run and another method (with the segue in) is run instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Gesture Recognizer in the cell creation method: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *imageTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
    imageTap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
    imageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.turnThumbnailImage addGestureRecognizer:imageTap];
```